# Musical duel between Zhou yu and Zhuge Liang

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, red-cliff

When Zhuge goes to take help from Zhou yu in *Red Cliff*, they have one musical duel, you can see it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3SIC6RGKBk). It was Quite interesting.

I am not good with music, but I heard that each tone of Zhou is **louder** while the reply of Zhuge is a little bit **in low tone** and one can understand that it's in a **peaceful manner**.

After that duel, Lu su told Zhuge that *"We have not talked on the point which is the reason for the visit."* And Zhuge replies that they will fight together.

So, I just want to know if it was a simple musical duet or **if they have communicated with their music, and if yes, what was the chat about?**

Comment: woo's movie always have pleasant music..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumptions are right on the money. **The scene was constructed to let these two heroes bond as well as communicate, displaying the similarities and the contrasts between them.** Says the film's director John Woo in [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHV8SbmDDqg):

> First of all, our character [Zhou Yu], played by Tony Leung - in real history, he was a musician *[[see last paragraph here]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_Yu#Personal_life)*. He knows so much about music, but at the meantime, he was always a great leader. And I took the idea of jazz. **I have desgined the scene to let the two heroes, Zhou Yu and Zhuge Liang, Tony and Takeshi - they were using music to communicate each other.** I think it made the scene more fun and I had never seen anything like it before in any of the Chinese movies.

Actor Takeshi Kaneshiro who plays Zhuge Liang [elaborates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Njddj4sWhLE) about the musical duel:

> **The director** said a high level skill wasn't that important. He **wanted us to communicate the contrast of war and peace between the two heroes, and he wanted us to do it by playing the zither.** The facial expression was what was important.

The scene is also a thematic and cinematic homage to the famous [guitar and banjo 'duel'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yspZTBNnE5I) between two players from different walks of life in John Boorman's film [*Deliverance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deliverance), where a suburban man and a rural boy **bond over a musical duet**. Similarly, Zhuge and Zhou 'duel' to relieve the tension between them, display their different ideologies and eventually understand each other and unite. From Kenneth E. Hall's book [*John Woo: The Films*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786440406):

> [*Red Cliff*] Editor David Wu confirmed that his intent was to recall the Boorman film. [...] Unlike the scene in *'Deliverance'* Woo's scene is a case of warfare by other means. **The latent rivalry between leaders Zhuge Liang and Zhou Yu must be resolved, and the musical duel is a harmless means of partially defusing it.**

And I think I agree with your analysis of their styles. It makes sense that Zhou, the militant leader, will initially display a more aggressive tone while Zhuge, the clever and calm strategist who's hinted to be of humble farming origins, will prefer a more subtle, reflective tune. But I'd say that in the end, **their styles more or less *combine* into a turbulent, rhytmic duet - telling us our two heroes must now join forces, and win the war together.**

Comment: a very very deep answer, what I expected, and thanks for sharing Zhou yu's wiki, I found that "If there is a problem with the tune, Zhou Yu will look up.".. thanks!! It will be great if you add more info like this, if possible..

Comment: Thanks for replying (and for the interesting question). I did debate including that detail about Zhou Yu, but wasn't 100% sure it fit the scene and opted for a breadcrumb trail instead. ;)